# Responsive Isotope (Masonry) + imagesLoaded + LazyLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, imagesloaded, lazy-loading

As with many users I've been running into the common overlap issue when using isotope. I tried integrating imagesLoaded and it worked to some extent, but because I want to display 100+ photos - it's not efficient to wait for all photos to load before laying out isotope. Plus all 100 images load in a single column before isotope fires in. I tried to add LazyLoad to the equation as well, to no avail. After endless research and reading I came to the conclusion that what I wanted to achieve was not possible until I came across this site:

http://www.erikjohanssonphoto.com/

This is exactly what I've been striving to achieve. As you can see all images load in their proper position regardless of which images load first. There is no relayout after images have been loaded, yet it is progressive as you scroll down more images are revealed. Most importantly the setup is responsive. The grid items scale accordingly as you resize the window and the number of columns changes as well with every set increment.

Any help or advice in achieving this would be highly appreciated!

HTML

```
<body>

<div id="container" class="fluid">
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" data-original="images/1.jpg"></div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/2.jpg" data-original="images/2.jpg"></div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/3.jpg" data-original="images/3.jpg"></div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/4.jpg" data-original="images/4.jpg"></div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/5.jpg" data-original="images/5.jpg"></div>
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/6.jpg" data-original="images/6.jpg"></div>
<div></div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
.container, .header {
margin: auto;
text-align: center;}

#container.fluid .item {
width:  25%; }

#container.fluid .item img {
display: block;
width: 100%;}
```

JS

```
$(window).load(function(){
var $container = $('#container');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',   
});

$('.item img').addClass('not-loaded');
$('.item img.not-loaded').lazyload({
    effect: 'fadeIn',
    load: function() {
        // Disable trigger on this image
        $(this).removeClass("not-loaded");
        $container.isotope('reload');
    }
});
$('.item img.not-loaded').trigger('scroll');
});
});
```

Comment: and it is made by [Squarespace](http://www.squarespace.com/home/overview/) it seems. They have a free trial to build a website as well. One can use isotope, lazyload and imagesloaded BTW.

Comment: Thanks! You're right it is made with squarespace, but I don't want to use squarespace. Any idea how to replicate those results using isotope lazyload and imagesloaded?

Comment: Here are some demos: http://codepen.io/aFarkas/pen/VYGvde, http://codepen.io/aFarkas/pen/JdrXjm. Read this: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes#user-content-specify-dimensions. related Issue: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/issues/118

Comment: @alexanderfarkas Thank you so much!! This really helped. :D

Comment: @TheWaldorf Happy to help

Comment: @TheWaldorf did you manage to get the resize feature added to the codepen example above?